# Is it correct to measure R coefficient for LOG LIN models

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, log-linear

I have a model where the $y$ is very skewed and I convert it to log and run a log linear model.

But, I have doubts about the way to measure the error, because in the original variables the error would be much bigger than in log variables. Are there any other ways to measure the error?

I would prefer to use GEP instead of log linear. But the idea is to find simple coefficients to explain. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: In what way are you measuring error now? What does GEP mean?

Comment: R squared in the log lin model. GEP = genetic programming.